# xml is shown instead of site

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am learning google cloud so I tried to deploy my react app there using storage service. For that i created a bucket called travelfrontend and uploaded the files and folders from build folder which is generated when using `yarn build`. I do not have any domain so i tried to access from https://storage.googleapis.com/travelfrontend but it shows me the following

[image]

I could not make it live. Did I miss anything to make it live?

Answer (score 3):

In order to serve the static content generated after running `yarn build` you need to set the `MainPageSuffix` property on your GCS bucket. This property will cause the file you specify (for example "index.html") to be served when accessing the root URL.

However, the bucket needs to be created and configured as stated in the following ["Hosting a static website" docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). Note that you will have to point a custom domain to Cloud Storage by using a CNAME record.

After that, you will be able to set the `MainPageSuffix` as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages)

More info about CGS static website configuration can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website)

Hope this helps

Comment: can't i have bucket without domain name to host a static site? By without domain name, i mean can't i use such domain https://storage.googleapis.com/travelfrontend for just demo purpose?

Comment: You can access the main page manually by using a URL like https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>/index.html. The issue is that by default, after building the react app, the links to its resources would have the following format: "/favicon.ico". This will cause the browser to look for the resources in https://storage.googleapis.com/<resource>, which won't work.
You can overcome this by adding to your package.json the following: `"homepage": "https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket-name>"`
Then, after building, the links in your html file will point to the correct location of the files.

Comment: that way("homepage": "https://storage.googleapis.com/travelfrontend",) if i do i have to first go to this route `https://storage.googleapis.com/travelfrontend/index.html` where i get 'No match for /travelfrontend/index.html' route in the home page but if i click on login or any other link then it works as expected like `https://storage.googleapis.com/auth/login` but if i refresh then it shows xml error `<Code>MissingSecurityHeader</Code>`

Comment: React is out of my area of expertise, but it seems that there might be something else in you app that you have to configure in order to use the "/travelfrontend" subdirectory as base URL.

In my opinion, it would be best to create a Cloud Storage Bucket as described in the [Hosting a static website docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) that I mentioned in my answer

Comment: i get such issue when i refresh now `Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to auth/login.` Thanks for mentioning that link but right now i do not have any domain so just for demo purpose I am trying this way.

Comment: This is because you are trying to access https://storage.googleapis.com/<something>. This URL is pointing to something that is not in your bucket. Hence the error.
This article may be helpful in order to configure your app to be hosted in a URL with a subdirectory https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1