# MainPageSuffix for static site not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage, static-site

I have searched for this question, but none of the responses help me.

Following the tutorial, I have created a new bucket ([www.stepwiserefinement.co.uk](http://www.stepwiserefinement.co.uk)) and it contains a static site, including index.html and error.html.

I have used the Console to set these as defaults for the base url and unknown files.

When I access the http://www.stepwiserefinement.co.uk URL, I get an XML listing of the files; I should be seeing index.html.

gustily correctly reports

```
{"mainPageSuffix": "/index.html", "notFoundPage": "/error.html"}
```

but if I access the domain with no path, the response is

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
</Details>
</Error>
```

No https, no load balancer needed.
Missing something.
Suggestions please.

Comment: Did you configure website support on the bucket? For example, what do you get when you run the command `gsutil web get gs://www.stepwiserefinement.co.uk`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xml is shown instead of site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947355/xml-is-shown-instead-of-site)

Comment: The values are set.
peter_dot_ward@cloudshell:~ (helpful-range-261712)$ gsutil web get gs://www.stepwiserefinement.co.uk
{"mainPageSuffix": "index.html", "notFoundPage": "error.html"}
The files are present. But when I access the domain with no path, I just get an XML directory listing, or a "unable to list" depending on which access mode I set. SO these settings are not taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple issues here.

1. Your site still loads in HTTPS when you put it in the browser. The connection is somehow upgrading you to SSL. And if you're in SSL, you need the load [balancer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#lb-ssl). As opposed to [these](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website-http) instructions without load balancer. Maybe you have SSL turned on with your registrar or somewhere else.
2. I only get 404 error. Not sure how you got "Access denied". But it could also be a secondary issue because when enabled properly, no access control is present. For example, it says [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website-http#create-bucket) under step 3 "*selected **Uniform** for Access Control*". This removes access control.

Let us know if you followed the last article completely

Edit: Also, out of curiosity, try making the bucket [public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) (without Uniform), if it doesn't work above.